# RVIZ octomap plugin doesn't show produced octomap

Tags: rviz, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently trying to produce octomap using octomap_server and my laser range finder in gazebo. Everything seems to work fine, data is published into octoma_server and then published into /octomap_binary topic. Then I'm using rviz octomap plugin to visualize final octomap. Rviz says that everything is ok, but I can't see any visualization of octomap at all...

The funny thing is that yesterday I was able to visualize everything. But then I started to play with newer versions of octomap and tried to override ROS source version of octomap with newer version from git. Then I went through some problems, so I decided to move back to the state when everything worked.

Unfortunately it seems like I forgot on something which is causing me this trouble... Does anybody know where the problem could be? I tried reinstalling whole ros, but this also doesn't do anything...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224125/rviz-octomap-plugin-doesn%27t-show-produced-octomap/) by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 826 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so I was able to figure this out... After some reinstalling etc. I displayed occupancy map generated from octomap_server. But this map seemed quite small and not accurate. Then I saw that I didn't change maximum range of my laser sensor in octomap_mapping.launch. After that I was again able to see the map properly...

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2016-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2017-09-16**:
Hey! Can you please explain me how you displayed occupancy_map. I have added a question related to this here: https://answers.ros.org/question/271044/how-to-visualize-3d-map-in-rviz-using-octomap/